# mysql query help in two table

Tags: mysql

I have two table table1 and table2 
table1:
id  amount
1 394
2 897
2 345
3 123

table2:
id amount
2 876
3 890
3 876
4 908

I need to generate table3. join two table and SUM id wise and show top 30 amount holder.
table3:
id amount
2 2118
3 1889
4 908
1 394

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get data in followng way:

```
select table3.id, SUM (table3.amount) AS amount
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2) table3 
GROUP BY table3.id
```

If you want to create table with above data, you can do like this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table select table3.id, SUM (table3.amount) AS amount
                       FROM 
                       (SELECT * FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2) table3 
                       GROUP BY table3.id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query

```
SELECT a.id, SUM(a.amount)
FROM (
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2) AS a
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY SUM(a.amount)
LIMIT 30 DESC;
```

Above query will generate results, now to create new table use following

```
CREATE TABLE table3(
    SELECT a.id, SUM(a.amount)
    FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM table2) AS a
    GROUP BY a.id
    ORDER BY SUM(a.amount)
    LIMIT 30 DESC);
```

Hope this helps...